# HTML5/JS drops FPS on maximized window

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm playing with HTML5/JavaScript using canvas, I've noticed a huge drop on FPS whenever the browser windows get maximized. Initially I thought it was on the specific browser I'm using, but I test all the browser IE,FF,OP,CH all drops the frames per seconds when maximized at least 50% or more. Any hint why is this the case? thanks.

Comment: Here's a link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vB4cjuPb_Dk&list=PL902122B327461763